# Read AD group from azure function using service principal authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to read and list members of a particular AD group using powershell script using azure function. To connect AD i am using service principal. Connecting to AzureAD is successful, but trying to access AD group gives me an error (at this stage i just want to get a specific group and echo it):

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Error occurred while executing GetGroups 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: <requestID>
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 14 Oct 2019 20:40:26 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

Why is that happening? did anyone use azuread module commands within azure function? I have granted ms graph permissions for this app:
[image]

```
$Script={
    param ()
    ##Save AzureAD module to the modules folder before publishing
    Import-Module .\modules\AzureAD

    $appId = "<AppId>"
    $thumb = "<CertThumb>"
    $tenantId = "TenantID"
    Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -ApplicationId  $appId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb

    $groupName = "<Name of the group>"

    $group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $groupName 
    #or
    #$group = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId "<object id>"

    echo $group
}

&$env:64bitPowerShellPath -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Command $Script
```

Note that my code is wrapped into $Script variable and last line is added to make the code work as a temporary workaround until AD modul will be added to PS Core: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/232

Comment: Could you try giving it similar permissions on AAD Graph API? (Windows Azure Active Directory) Just a hunch but I remember some PowerShell cmdlets used this older API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another reply, adding the service principal as a directory role is one way, but you should note it will give your service principal other permissions, e.g. `create group`, `delete group`.

Actually the issue was caused by you grant the wrong permission, you need to grant the `Azure Active Directory Graph` with `Directory.Read.All` Application permission instead of `Microsoft Graph`, because the command `Get-AzureADGroup` essentially calls the `Azure Active Directory Graph`.

[image]

**Note**: When test the command in local, after granting the permission, close your powershell session and open a new one, login again and run the command. If you run that in function, maybe restart the function app to make sure the permission has affected.

Comment: Thanks @Joy Wang for reply, i will try this out and tell you what is the result tomorrow when i will get admin permission.

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture you provided, you have assigned some graph API permissions to the service principal. After you do that, you just can call some graph API with the service principal. If you want to use Azure AD PowerShell module with service principal to manage Azure AD, you need to assign Azure AD role to the service principal. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0.

Regarding how to create service principal and assign role, please refer to the following script.

```
# Login to Azure AD PowerShell With Admin Account
Connect-AzureAD 

# Create the self signed cert
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate  = $currentDate.AddYears(1)
$notAfter  = $endDate.AddYears(1)
$pwd  = "<password>"
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName com.foo.bar -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $notAfter).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath c:\temp\examplecert.pfx -Password $pwd

# Load the certificate
$cert  = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("C:\temp\examplecert.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())


# Create the Azure Active Directory Application
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "test123" -IdentifierUris "https://test123"
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "Test123" -StartDate $currentDate -EndDate $endDate -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue

# Create the Service Principal and connect it to the Application
$sp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $application.AppId

# Give the Service Principal Reader access to the current tenant (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole)
#Regarding the Azure AD role, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-delegate-by-task
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "role name"}
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId
```

Comment: Tried it already, i don't have sufficient permisison to do so.

Comment: @bryniek If you want to run the script, I need to be Global Admin.